# Android delay text

Tags: android, handler, delay

I want to set text to 25 buttons but have each text appear after 5 seconds. I've tried using tons of different methods. I tried using Thread.sleep(5000) but my program crashed. Then I attempted to create a Handler but it's crashing. Can someone please tell me why? Or is there another way I am supposed delay the text:

*Note: In my code I used the findViewById method but decided to not post it here for sake of simplicity and repetition -- so that is not the issue.

```
public class Game extends Activity {

protected List<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();
protected String letters[]; 
protected List<Button> button_list = new ArrayList<Button>();   
 Button b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, 
        b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, b17, b18, b19, b20,
        b21, b22, b23, b24;

 Random rand = new Random();
 int random_counter;
 int my_list_counter = 25;
 int i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);
    letters = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j",
                           "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
                           "u", "v", "w", "x", "y"};
    Button[] bttn_arr = new Button[] {b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, 
            b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, b17, b18, b19, b20,
            b21, b22, b23, b24};


    my_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(letters));

    button_list.addAll(Arrays.asList(bttn_arr));

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (i=0; i<25; i++){
                random_counter = rand.nextInt(my_list_counter);
                button_list.get(i).setText(my_list.get(random_counter));
                my_list.remove(my_list.get(random_counter));
                my_list_counter--;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: **never** use Thread.sleep in the UI thread. The handler is the way to go. If your program crashes, check out the exception you get in the console, probably there's a null pointer exception or something like that. And by the way, you are scheduling 25 calls at the same time to the same runnable, be careful, this may grow exponentially

Comment: thanks for your advice. I am still trying to figure out the problem. I am implementing Kaylwin's answer but there still seems to be a bug as I posted below. After changing Kaylwin's code a bit, the program waits 5 seconds then displays ALL the text. It doesn't display each text every 5 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adapting this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
       final String message = "Hello" + i;
        Runnable x = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                Log.i("Hello", message);

            }
        };

       Handler handler = new Handler();
       //Run the code in runnable x at increasing time intervals of 5 seconds
       handler.postAtTime(x, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + i*5000);

    }

}
```

This code will print out "hello" + i (ex. hello1 then hello2 then hello3 etc.) every 5 seconds. If you adapt your code to this it will run every 5 seconds. In the previous instance the handler was posting and running all the runnables at once, now it posts all the runnables at once, except with each one's start time increase by 5 seconds ( see handler.postAtTime(...) ) . Hope this helps!

Comment: I used your code but there seems to be an error. I am debugging now to see if I can figure it out. It runs the loop 25 times before entering the run method.

Comment: and after 5 seconds it displays all the text. It doesn't do it one-by-one. Hm... any ideas?

Comment: @user2456977 I misunderstood your problem so I changed my answer to make them display one by one.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Handler like this**

```
for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

              //do something here

            }
        }, 5000);
 }
```